# Pass the Json value to other ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am getting this from the webservice. I am showing the Address into the table.
But i have to do this that on click of each cell related latitude and longitude will be send to other viewController.
What to do can Anyone help me.

```
   "registrationID": "5"
    "emailAdd": "gautam.kumar@eyeforweb.com"
    "userPassword": "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b"
    "orgPassword": "123456"
    "Name": "Gautam Kumar"
    "userStatus": "1"
    "registrationDate": "1460633115"
    "address": "Paschim vihar,jwalaheri"
    "city": "kanpur"
    "state": "Delhi"
    "zip": ""
    "lat": "28.6139391"
    "lng": "77.2090212"
    "phone1": ""
    "phone2": ""
    "country": "India"
    "phoneAdd": "9990688436"
    "timezone": "US/Hawaii"
    "disclamair": "1"
    }-
    1:  {
    "id": "6"
    "user_id": "5"
    "address": "Delhi"
    "city": "delhi"
    "state": "Delhi"
    "country": "India"
    "lat": "28.6618976"
    "lng": "77.2273958"
    "adddate": "2016-09-21 07:23:10"
    }-
    2:  {
    "id": "15"
    "user_id": "5"
    "address": "California"
    "city": "California"
    "state": "California"
    "country": "United States"
    "lat": "36.778261"
    "lng": "-119.4179324"
    "adddate": "2016-09-21 11:26:13"
    }-
    3:  {
    "id": "19"
    "user_id": "5"
    "address": "nyc"
    "city": "nyc"
    "state": "New York"
    "country": "United States"
    "lat": "40.7028061"
    "lng": "-74.01333"
    "adddate": "2016-09-21 12:07:02"
    }-
    4:  {
    "id": "21"
    "user_id": "5"
    "address": "sdfasdfdsaf"
    "city": "sdfsdfs"
    "state": "Kramerville"
    "country": "South Africa"
    "lat": ""
    "lng": ""
    "adddate": "2016-09-22 05:16:32"
    }
```

Comment: save all the data in a custom business object class and pass that object to next VC

Comment: you have two Viewcontroller first one show these data in cell and click on perticular cell and pass the data from one view controller to another view controller am i right?

Comment: yes @AmitSrivastava

Comment: are  you  pushing view controller ? or you just want to pass data to next VC ?

Comment: just pass the data to next VC @AnjaliBhimani

Comment: please see this answer and tell me any problem

Comment: then you can use custom delegate if only you want to pass data and not pushing a vc

Answer (score 2):

**In Viewcontroller A**

Save the data in one nsmutablearray(viewarrayA) and show in tableview for using and didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
viewcontrollerB *objviewcontrollerB=[viewcontrollerB alloc]init];
objviewcontrollerB.viewArray=[viewarrayA objectatindex:indexpath.row]
}
```

**IN Viewcontroller B**

viewcontrollerB.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *viewArray;
```

viewcontrollerB.m

```
@synthesize viewArray;
```

create the one array(viewArray) in viewcontrollerB.h and synthesize in ViewcontrollerA.m and after that you have to receave the data from another view controller in this array.

Comment: but viewarray contains which value?lat or lng ?

Comment: what do you want lat or long if you want to lat u can use `[ [viewarrayA objectatindex:indexpath.row]valueForKey:@"lat"]` or long you can use this `[ [viewarrayA objectatindex:indexpath.row]valueForKey:@"lng"]`

Comment: i want both values in separate strings

Comment: means that you want to string_lat=@"28.6139391@" and string_lng=@"77.2090212"; in the next VC.

Comment: create the two  nsstring in viewcontrollerB.h and `@property (nonatomic, strong) NString * string_lat;` &` @property (nonatomic, strong) NString * string_lng;`  and then pass the value to using this string in viewcontroller.A in didSelectRowAtIndexPath `viewcontrollerB *objviewcontrollerB=[viewcontrollerB alloc]init];
objviewcontrollerB.string_lat=[ [viewarrayA objectatindex:indexpath.row]valueForKey:@"lat"]  objviewcontrollerB. string_lng =[ [viewarrayA objectatindex:indexpath.row]valueForKey:@"lat"]  `